# VS Code Snippets automatic synchronizer?

Tags: visual-studio, code-snippets

I use more than one machine for development in VS 2008. Is there a tool to automatically synchronize the snippets between the machines? Same concept of synchronizing  browsers' bookmark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Syncplicity.com](http://Syncplicity.com)

Answer (score 1):

If you have Vista and the LiveMesh client installed try [this suggestion](http://weblogs.asp.net/lduveau/archive/2008/06/30/sync-your-visual-studio-settings-with-live-mesh.aspx)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already know what files you need/want sync'd then some additional options to Mesh would be to tool-out.  Maybe look at SyncToy or SyncBack to keeps these collection of files centralized - then have all your machines pull from the central data store.

There is also [Live Sync](https://sync.live.com/) (formery FolderShare) which works over the internet.

Answer (score 0):

The machines are in different locations, home and work so software like SyncToy won't work.
I don't know about SyncBack. It's not clear from their web site if it can be done over the web. I can't find the client software on MS's site for Live Mesh.

I will check ideas here:
http://lifehacker.com/372175/free-ways-to-synchronize-folders-between-computers

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these:

1) http://www.getdropbox.com

2) https://www.foldershare.com/welcome.aspx

3) Microsoft Office Groove

I personally use SVN.

Answer (score 0):

I tried foldershare and did all the setup and it's not syncing. Also when I chose On Demand type of synchronization instead of Automatic, I expected to see an option to trigger the synchronization manually and I couldn't find it. I didn't like the software.

Looked around and found syncplicity and it works fine.